# Открыть видео и получить с него кадры

Tags: java, видео, стеганография

Мне нужно написать стеганографическую програму, суть которой в том что в видео формата avi нужно зашифровати доковский документ. Я уже перепробовала и Xuggle и JML, но ничего. По Xuggle не найшла ни одного учебника, а JML транслирует видео через URL адрес. Посоветуте к чему еще обратиться, чтобы реализовать мою задачу.

Comment: что на счет того, чтобы залить видео на ютуб и оттуда взять, затем можно будет придумать способ и обработать локально?

Comment: @michael_best можете дать полностью хотябы прибилизительный код с подключеными с xuggler  папками?

Comment: нет, если бы мог, я написал бы ответ)